# Test Drive - Issue while login for taking test drive option from app exchange

Tags: appexchange

we developed an app and now currently it is listed on AppExchange.

I got problem to login from app exchange.
whenever we click take a test drive option from app exchange a new window will appears it asks verification code..

But the requirement is no need to ask verification code. Customers can click on that option they will login with their credentials and use it in trail mode.

And one more issue is once we login we can't see any dashboards.
it showing insufficient privileges error.

Any one can help me how to fix this issues???

Comment: I would like to know if you managed the issue with verification code. My company developed an app and when we click on test drive, the verification code is required in order to install the app, but, as you know, this should not happen.